# How To Call WP_Query From A Subdomain?

Tags: wp-query, subdomains

I have a PHP script running in WordPress, that uses a `WP_Query` to get the posts from one of my subdomains and return it as a JSON string. The script only receives the post data if I call it using the correct subdomain.

For example, if I go to `news.example.com/api/news.php`, the JSON prints correctly, but if I go to `www.example.com/api/news.php` it only prints an empty array.

How can I call a single script that will get data from a subdomain, even if I call it using the main domain? Or even better, if I call it from any subdomain?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console? This might be a same origin issue

Comment: @czerspalace Nope, no errors

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the [WP API](http://wp-api.org/)?

You could then pull posts from a URL like this ...

```
http://subdomain.example.com/wp-json/posts
```

You can also set custom post types to use the WP API and then access them also in a similar manner, you would need to add the following to your CPT args:

```
$args = array(
         //...
        'show_in_rest'       => true,
        'rest_base'          => 'books-api',
        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Posts_Controller',
       )
    );
```

Take a look at: http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/custom-content-types/

You can even use WP_Query parameters like this:

`http://subdomain.example.com/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=2&filter[order]=ASC`

You could use jQuery.getJSON() to get the data cross domain:

```
 $.getJSON('http://subdomain.example.com/wp-json/posts', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: Interesting, but how would it solve the problem of accessing the content from a different subdomain? Also, from what I've read, you cannot do authentication with the Rest API, which some of my feeds would require.

Comment: I'm obviously not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve, but could you not force the user to authenticate before they see a page with any of the feeds on?  This should work cross-domain using jQuery.getJSON() I think, I've added to my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can include the wordpress functions in any *.php file anywhere on your server. You don`t have to run the script inside the actual WP installation:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/absolute/path/to/your/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php');
require('/absolute/path/to/your/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
```

Just include the headers and for admin-functions the admin.php. Then you can WP-Query() in this (external) file.

Regards Tom